# nsdocument subclass variable is somehow reset to nil after a proper initialization: why?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument, nswindowcontroller

I have a disappearing pointer *db*; the value is properly set during creation of an `NSDocument` but at the moment I want to open a sub window, the value has changed to `nil`! I have the following in an `NSDocument` subclass:

```
 @interface MW_Document : NSDocument
 {
     MW_WorkerWindowController *workerController;
     __strong MW_db *db;
 }

 - (IBAction)showWorkerManagementPanel:(id)sender;
 //- (IBAction)showSkillManagementPanel:(id)sender;
```

The implementation contains this:

```
 - (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
 {
     [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];
     if (![self db]) {
         db = [[MW_db alloc] init];
         NSLog ( @"Debug - Init of db: [%ld]", db ); // never mind the casting problem
     }
 }
```

*db* points at something other than nil, a true address.

Later on, I want to open a window and have this in the implementation of the same `NSDocument` subclass:

```
 - (IBAction)showWorkerManagementWindow:(id)sender
 {
     if ( !workerController) {
         workerController = [[MW_WorkerWindowController alloc] initWithDb:db];
     }
     [workerController showWindow:self];
 }
```

I put a break point at the first line, and look at the value of *db*. It is nil, but I have **no** idea why. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint in `windowControllerDidLoadNib:`? To be more specific, are you sure that `db = [[MW_db alloc] init];` is actually called *before* `workerController = [[MW_WorkerWindowController alloc] initWithDb:db];`? It might be that `workerController` does not load its NIB until the `-[showWindow:]` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a lazy accessor:

```
- (MW_db *)db
{
    if (db == nil) {
        db = [[MW_db alloc] init];
    }
    return db;
}
```

And then use it instead of the ivar:

```
workerController = [[MW_WorkerWindowController alloc] initWithDb:[self db]];
```

Comment: Is such a lazy accessor a good general alternative to the ivar initialization? My guess is that it is not good for performance, but that it is useful for debugging problems like the current one. Is that correct?

Comment: It depends, but most of the time lazy getters is the best alternative to direct ivar initialization in the `-[init]`. And they are especially good for performance, because you `malloc` memory only when you really need an object. So, if you properly implement lazy access, the memory footprint of the app will be as small as possible.

Comment: How about the check for nil, every time you request the value? This may be very inexpensive, in which case the memory management advantage that you laid out above is much more important! Are you able to comment on how computationally expensive a nil-check is?

Comment: It is the same as comparing two integer numbers, so it must be very computationally cheap. Anyway, you should not worry about this while writing code. First, make it *readable* and *working*, and only then optimize using Instruments.